# Complete Xml Validation

Tags: java, xml

Is it possible to validate xml against xsd which should show all the failures present in xml? I'm using java to validate. But the validator showing first failure. I need to get all the failures in the xml.

Comment: II do not know if it is possible to display all errors. Consider a case where you missed a closing bracket: `<root <child attr="val"></child></root>`. When the parser discovers that a `>` is missing for the root, it has discovered an error which it is able to report. It will however not be able to continue parsing the document, as it is not well formed xml. So it will not be possible to verify against the schema whether `child` is a valid child of `root` or whether `attr` is a valid attribute of `child`. Before the parser can do that verification, you must fix the closing bracket error.

Comment: I think the question was about validation errors, not well-formedness errors. Of course, it's still true that the "number of errors" is somewhat subjective, for example if two elements appear in the wrong order the processor might report this as one error or as two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own [ErrorHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) to capture all exceptions. See this article here for details:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/index.html#N101B3